# package and launch activity is not displaying in appium console?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

hi i am new to Appium testing. when i tried to add apk file([selendroid apk file](http://selendroid.io/setup.html))
i unable to to get package name and launch activity on appium console.i tried with many answers like spaces in in the apk file etc.. but still i am not getting a perfect answers for that.

i followed the following docs [check here](http://learn-automation.com/automate-native-applications-using-appiumselenium/) to getstarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for package name and launch activity of your apk file. Install the apk file in device and run the following commands in terminal.

For package name:

```
adb shell 'pm list package -f' |grep <Application Name>
```

For activity name:

```
adb shell dumpsys package | grep -i "<Package Name>" |grep Activity
```

Comment: what is grep, my system is not recognizing it.

Comment: `grep` is a command-line utility for searching plain-text data sets for lines matching a regular expression.   
If your are using unix operating system than `find` instead of `grap`
`adb shell pm list package -f | find <Application Name>
Ex. adb shell pm list package -f | find "calculator"`

Comment: this is the error i am getting , i am using windows-7    'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Use the command, as i mentioned above.
`adb shell pm list package -f | find "<Application Name>"`
and
`adb shell dumpsys package | find -i "<Package Name>" | find Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, the issue is fixed now. I uninstalled and reinstalled the appium.exe and set up the environment variable for sdk again.
as ANDROID_HOME : `path to your android sdk`